# Sending a message to my bot using the Direct Line v3.0 NuGet package

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to use the [Direct Line v3.0 NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine/3.0.0-beta) to send a message to my bot. I am following the [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine) on Github, but I'm not getting the behavior I expect.

Here is the sample code:

```cs
DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient(directLineSecret);        
var conversation = await client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();

while (true)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    if (input.ToLower() == "exit")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if (input.Length > 0)
        {
            Activity userMessage = new Activity
            {
                From = new ChannelAccount(fromUser),
                Text = input,
                Type = ActivityTypes.Message
            };

            await client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, userMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code:

```cs
var directLineSecret = "MY_SECRET";
var client = new DirectLineClient(directLineSecret);
var conversation = await client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();

var testActivity = new Activity
{
    From = new ChannelAccount(name: "Proactive-Engine"),
    Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
    Text = "Hello from the PCE!"
};

var response = await client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, testActivity);
```

I'm logging all the messages my bot receives. I can talk to the bot at its endpoint on Azure using the Bot Emulator, so I have confidence that it's working through the web chat API. However when I run the code above, the bot logs only a `conversationUpdate` message. The message I send does not get logged, and the value of `response` is `null`.

I'm hoping someone can help me find out where I'm going wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how the demo instantiates `ChannelAccount`:

```
new ChannelAccount(fromUser)
```

Then look at the `ChannelAccount` constructor signature:

```
public ChannelAccount(string id = null, string name = null)
```

This means that `fromUser` is passed as `id`. But look at how you instantiated `ChannelAccount`:

```
new ChannelAccount(name: "Proactive-Engine")
```

That code doesn't pass an `id`, it passes a `name`. So, you can change it like this:

```
new ChannelAccount("Proactive-Engine")
```

If your chatbot needs the `name`, then instantiate like this:

```
new ChannelAccount("MyChatbotID", "MyChatbotName")
```

Comment: That was it. Feel pretty dumb, but that's how this stuff goes sometimes.

Thank you!